# MVC 3 DevExpress - Model Returned to Controller is Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

The problem is really simple, but I just can't seem to solve it. I am using Razor engine with DevExpress combo box.

I have this code:

**MODEL:**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public ActionResult OpenTest()
    {
        TestModel tm = new TestModel( );
        tm.Roles = new List<Role>( );

        tm.Roles.Add( new Role( ) { RoleId = 1, RoleName = "Role 1" } );
        tm.Roles.Add( new Role( ) { RoleId = 2, RoleName = "Role 2" } );
        tm.Roles.Add( new Role( ) { RoleId = 3, RoleName = "Role 3" } );

        return View( tm );
    }
```

Here I can successfully open the view, and data is displayed fine:

**VIEW**

```
@model TestDx.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OpenTest";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using ( Html.BeginForm( ) )
{
                        @Html.DevExpress( ).ComboBox(
                    settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "TestDx.Models.TestModel.Roles";
                        settings.Width = 120;
                        settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        settings.Properties.DropDownWidth = 300;
                        settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
                        settings.Properties.EnableCallbackMode = false;
                        settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 30;
                        settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
                        settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}";
                        settings.Properties.ValueField = "RoleID";
                        settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof( int );

                        settings.Properties.Columns.Add( "RoleID", "RoleID", 10 );
                        settings.Properties.Columns.Add( "RoleName", "RoleName", 100 );

                    } ).BindList( Model.Roles ).GetHtml( )
        <br />
            @Html.DevExpress().Button(
                    settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "btnSave";
                        settings.ClientEnabled = true;
                        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                        settings.ClientVisible = true;

                        settings.Text = "save";
                        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                        settings.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                    }).GetHtml()
}
```

Now all this is very simple, and I am not doing anything with it, just dispaying it. But when I click Save button, I get back to the controller, to this method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OpenTest( [ModelBinder( typeof( DevExpressEditorsBinder ) )]TestModel model )
        {
            if ( ModelState.IsValid )
            {
               //
            }

            return View( model );
        }
```

...and Model here is empty, Roles property is 0. I cannot understand why is that? Event the combo box name is the same as the property it is binding to, and I am sure using a recommended DevExpress binder.

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue would be nice to know the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your ComboBox is listing the type definition. Because you are passing in **TestModel** as the type, the name of your ComboBox should be the property where the role Id should be saved. So the binder is attempting to fill **model.TestDx.Models.TestModel.Roles** but can't find that field, and so nothing is getting filled. If you look at the formCollection objects you should see your ComboBox with the value.

A better solution would be to have **RoleID** specified in **TestModel**, and name the ComboBox simply **RoleID**. In that case RoleID should fill automatically on your save. Alternatively, you could specify the Bind field in the view, such as:

```
 @Html.DevExpress( ).ComboBox(
                    settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "TestDx.Models.TestModel.Roles";
                        settings.Width = 120;
                        settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        settings.Properties.DropDownWidth = 300;
                        settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
                        settings.Properties.EnableCallbackMode = false;
                        settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 30;
                        settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
                        settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}";
                        settings.Properties.ValueField = "RoleID";
                        settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof( int );

                        settings.Properties.Columns.Add( "RoleID", "RoleID", 10 );
                        settings.Properties.Columns.Add( "RoleName", "RoleName", 100 );

                    } ).BindList( Model.Roles )
                       .Bind(model.RoleID).GetHtml( )
```

This may work for your binding.

Answer (score 0):

The model is not been bound. Your RoleID name attribute must be different than Roles[listIndex].RoleID.
To bind lists into your Model, the input name should be `ListPropName[listIndex].PropNameInsideList`