# MVC DevExpress - Model Returned to Controller is Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have an extremely simple page.  It has a few devexpress textboxs and a devexpress button.

These textboxs are bound to specific fields within my model.

Upon clicking the button it shoots over to my action, upon reviewing the model in my action my fields are empty.  I initially had this working perfectly with @Html.TextBoxFors.  Upon adding in the Devexpress textboxs and textboxfors nothing works.

I have reviewed stackoverflow and have found no solution, although I have found a similar question, essentially identical but if I need to start a bounty I would rather do it on my own question, as far as code is concerned mine is very very similar to the one below. :

[MVC 3 DevExpress - Model Returned to Controller is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319969/mvc-3-devexpress-model-returned-to-controller-is-empty)

I have also reviewed devexpress's website and found this. :

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2886

The above is essentially a demo of how to properly do this.  My project and the other stackoverflow user's code are pretty much exactly the same as this.

I am assuming others have had this issue.  I have been attempting to get this to work for weeks now and still have had no luck.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**Code**

View

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MyModel>
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors;

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyModelSave", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
                   {
                       settings.Name = "txtId";
                       settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
                   }).Bind(Model.Id).GetHtml()
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
                   {
                       settings.Name = "txtName";
                       settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
                   }).Bind(Model.Name).GetHtml()
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DevExpress().Button(s =>
                     {
                        s.Name = "btnSave";
                        s.Images.Image.Url = "~/Images/save.png";
                        s.Text = string.Empty;
                        s.ToolTip = "Save";
                            s.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                        }).GetHtml()
    </div>
}
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyModelSave([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))]MyModel modelTest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                //Work with model
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Without it it is very hard to help you with your problem.

Comment: Added, but as I said the code is essentially the same as the link i provided.  I have tried about 45 variations of what i have posted here with no luck.

Comment: Your model property names and the TextBox settings Names should match. Try to write: `settings.Name = "Id";` and `settings.Name = "Name";` instead of txtId and txtName

Comment: Pure genius would you put this as an answer so I can mark you down?  I am new to MVC, you just saved my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the model binding your html input (TextBox) names and your model property names should match.

So your `DevExpress().TextBox`s need to have the same `settings.Name`s as your model properties:

```
<div>
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
           {
               settings.Name = "Id";
               settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
           }).Bind(Model.Id).GetHtml()
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
           {
               settings.Name = "Name";
               settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
           }).Bind(Model.Name).GetHtml()
</div>
```